# How to set the git property sslBackend = schannel in Spring Tool Suite 4

Tags: eclipse, https, egit, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to run git clone in Spring Tool Suite (eclipse) from local gitlab server.

I'm using HTTPS clone url and the server certificate is signed by our organization CA.

I'm getting the error: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.

The root certificate of the organization is in the Windows trusted certificates store.

I tried placing the git configuration in the path `%USERPROFILE%\.gitconfig` with the content:

```
[http]
    sslBackend = schannel
```

I can see in STS that the configuration was loaded in the eclipse preferences, but the error is still there.

Any idea how to get git commands in STS / Eclipse to trust the Windows certificate store?

Thanks,
Eyal

Answer (score 0):

found it...

I had to add to the java options in the SpringToolSuite4.ini

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=NUL
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT
```

Then java trusted the Windows keystore